# Casting generic to subtype

Tags: java, generics, casting

This is a follow up to: [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41459591/inheritence-using-java-generics-not-working-as-expected)

My following line of code does not work:

```
IAccount account = (AccountModel) new AccountRepository().getByEmail(emailaddress);
```

The returntype of `...getByEmail(...)` is `Model<Account>`, and `AccountModel` extends `Model<Account>`.
Yet I get a `java.lang.ClassCastException: models.Model cannot be cast to models.AccountModel` when I test it. I know this is because every `AccountModel` is a `Model<Account>`, but not the other way around.
Is there any way how I can make sure that I can fix this (or work around it).

```
public class AccountRepository extends Repository<Account> {

    public AccountRepository() {
        super(Account.class);
    }

    public Model<Account> getByEmail(String emailAddress) {
        return this.getCustomHqlSingle("FROM Account a WHERE a.emailAddress = '" + emailAddress + "'");
    }
}

public abstract class Repository<T> implements Serializable {
    protected final Model<T> getCustomHqlSingle(String hql) {
        List<Model<T>> t = this.getCustomHqlList(hql);
        if (t != null && !t.isEmpty()) {
            return t.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected final List<Model<T>> getCustomHqlList(String hql) {

        Session session = SESSION_FACTORY.openSession();

        try {
            session.beginTransaction();
            List<T> entities = session.createQuery(hql).getResultList();
            List<Model<T>> result = new ArrayList<>();
            for (T t : entities) {
                result.add(this.getByEntity(t));
            }
            return result;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
}
```

---

To the person that marked this question as duplicate, let me rephrase the following sentence from my question:

> I know this is because every `AccountModel` is a `Model<Account>`, but
>   not the other way around.

To

> I know this is because every `Dog` is an `Animal`, but not the other
>   way around.

Comment: That depends on what your real need is. If you need an `AccountModel`, you must make sure you get one, either by your account repository returning one to you or you construct it some way. Otherwise cast to a weaker type. Would casting to `IAccount` work?? (you probably have tried)

Comment: To put it another way, what is it that you need that means you cannot just work with a `Model<Account>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [explicit casting from super class to subclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4862960/explicit-casting-from-super-class-to-subclass)

Comment: I peeked in your previous question and saw that you return an Model<Account> instance in your getById method. Even though AccountModel extends Model<Account> doesnt mean that you can cast all Model<Account> instances to a AccountModel - only if it is in fact a instance of an AccountModel. Try to return a new AccountModel in your getByEmail method and see if that works.

Comment: Just use Model<Account> all the way and it will be fine.

Comment: @OleV.V. I want to return an IAccount because it has some extra methods (not variables) that aren't present in Model.

Comment: Let me guess, the object actually returned to you is of a runtime type that does not have those methods? In that case there is no easy way to “glue the extra methods on”.

Comment: @SabirKhan, this is hardly a duplicate since the asker already said s/he understands that the `ClassCastException` is because the returned object is not an `AccountModel`.

Comment: It would help to know what you're doing in `getByEmail` which is supposedly implemented by you? Right now I don't see why you can't just return an `AcountModel` there instead.

Comment: @stalet The reason why I return a Model<T> is because T is a JPA annotated entity, and my AccountRepository is also an implementation of Repository<T>. I will try and see if I instead make my Repositories depend on Models instead of Entities

Comment: @JornVernee I've added my implementation as requested.

Comment: So nobody has so called **solution** to his problem and still its not a duplicate. Why everybody keeps explaining same thing about cast etc that is already explained in linked question? Instead of discouraging him to go that way and labeling it as a **bad programming**, he is being encouraged to do a risky cast. Every language has its own limitations, this is one of them, know it and move on. Change your code. Current code will not fit in.

Answer (score 1):

You have to devise a method in which to convert a `Model<Account>` to an `AccountModel`. Taking the code from your other question you could add a constructor for this to the `AccountModel` class:

```
public class AccountModel extends Model<Account> implements IAccount {
    private static final AccountRepository REPOSITORY = new AccountRepository();

    public AccountModel(Account entity) {
        super(entity, REPOSITORY);
    }

    public AccountModel(Model<Account> model) { // <---
        super(model._entity, REPOSITORY);
    }

    // Method implementations...
}
```

Then change your `AccountRepository` class to return an `AccountModel` from `getByEmail`:

```
public AccountModel getByEmail(String emailAddress) {
    return new AccountModel(this.getCustomHqlSingle("FROM Account a WHERE a.emailAddress = '" + emailAddress + "'"));
}
```

Which uses the new constructor to convert the `Model<Account>` to an `AccountModel`.

---

There is another option. Rather than calling `new Model<T>(...)` in `Repository`, you could have implementing classes implement an abstract method that would return the desired `Model` type:

```
public abstract class Repository<T, R> implements Serializable
```

...

```
public Repository(Class<T> repositoryClass) {

    if (!Repository._initiated) 
        setup();

    this.cons = cons;
}

protected abstract R getModel(T entity, Repository<T> repo); // <--
```

Then somewhere in the factory methods:

```
public R getByFoo(...) {
   ...
   T t = session.get(_repositoryClass, ...);
   return getModel(t, this);
}
```

Where `AccountRepository` would return a new `AccountModel`:

```
public class AccountRepository extends Repository<Account, AccountModel> {

    public AccountRepository() {
        super(Account.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected AccountModel getModel(Account entity, Repository<Account> repo) {
        return new AccountModel(entity);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you understand why you get an error, let me try to explain something else about casting.

Except for some limited cases, the casting operator does not change the item being cast. Casting is an instruction to the compiler only, saying "My logic has guaranteed that the type of the cast object is different than the compiler can determine, so while you (the compiler) would tell me this is an error, I am certain that, at runtime, it will be fine. So don't give me an error".

It does NOT say "take this object and transform it into another, similar object". That operation is not possible in Java, thank heavens.

Comment: Is there any way how I can make sure that I can fix this (or work around it).

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. In order to fix the casting operation, your code must ensure the cast is legal. The compiler can tell you, sometimes, that there is never any way to cast one thing to another, but it cannot tell you there will be no ClassCastException. Instead of a cast, perhaps you can call a method that takes the object you have and instantiates the correct type of object with it? That's a stab in the dark; it would get you past the casting issue, but I have no idea whether it's appropriate in your application.